# swiftでXCTest実行時だけ処理されないコードを作りたい

Tags: swift, テスト

XCTestを使用しています。

例えば、以下のfunc aaaのmarker をテストしたいとします。
すると、tableView.reloadで落ちてしまいます。
ちなみにtableView.reloadはテストの結果に影響しません。

そこで、tableView.reloadをこのテストの時だけコメントアウト
しておくと、問題なくテストは実行できます。

しかし、他のテストの時は、tableView.reloadは必要です。

つまり、func aaaをテストしたいときは、
tableView.reloadをコメントアウトし、
他のテストをしたいときは、func aaaをコメントアウトしておかなければ
なりません。

TableViewのところで落ちるので、TableViewの初期化を行う
ViewDidLoad（　）を　テストのsetUpで読んでみても、
TableView.delegateのところで落ちてしまいます。

このような場合、どのような方法が有りますでしょうか？

```
var marker = 0
func aaa ( ) {
  marker = 1

  tableView.reload
}

＝＝＝　test　＝＝＝＝
func testAAA () {
  aaa
  XCTAssertEqual ( marker, 1, "")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

コンパイルフラグを用いることで可能です。
http://qiita.com/qmihara/items/a6b88b74fe64e1e05ca4

今回の場合に限って言えば、tabelViewの値がnilが入っているため落ちているのではないかと思われます。インスタンスを代入することで解決するかもしれません。